# Exibir somente mês e ano no calendar do primefaces

Tags: primefaces

Como `remover os dias` do componente calendar do [primefaces](/questions/tagged/primefaces)?

Tentei a configuração abaixo, mas os dias são exibidos quando o componente é rederizado.

```
<p:calendar id="dataTeste" pattern="MM/yyyy" />
```

Eis a imagem do componente renderizado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O componente do Primefaces não dá suporte a isso nativamente.

Opções seriam:

- Customizar o componente ([como nesta resposta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16194165/1683070)).
- Usar um plugin de terceiros como o [monthPicker](http://lucianocosta.info/jquery.mtz.monthpicker/) (indicado na questão citada), aplicando-o numa caixa de texto nativa do PrimeFaces.
- Construir seu próprio componente JSF (talvez usando o plugin do item anterior).

Entretanto, a não ser que a questão visual seja algo muito necessário, talvez uma solução mais simples seja a recomendada. Use simplesmente uma combo com o intervalo de datas possíveis, cada item contendo `mês/ano`. Ou ainda duas combos, uma com mês e outra com ano.

Particularmente, Não vejo vantagem alguma como usuário em ter que pressionar setas para avançar ou retroceder o mês, pois dá mais trabalho se eu quiser ir para uma data mais longe.

Answer (score 4):

Tópico antigo, mas vou deixar uma solução alternativa que usa javascript e CSS para solucionar este problema...

OBS: Testado no Primefaces 5.2...

```js
function setData(){
  ano = $("#data .ui-datepicker-year").val();
  mes = $("#data .ui-datepicker-month").val();
  $('#data_input').val(('0' + (++mes)).slice(-2)+'/'+ano);   
}

$( "#data .ui-datepicker-month" ).change(function() {
  setData();   
});

$( "#daa .ui-datepicker-year" ).change(function() {
  setData();   
});
```

```
.ui-datepicker-inline .ui-datepicker-calendar{
  display: none;        
}
```

```html
<p:calendar id="data" value="#{bean.data}" mode="inline" navigator="true" pattern="MM/yyyy"/>
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado do código]

Comment: Alternativa interessante! Mais fácil que criar as combos separadamente. Só precisa tomar cuidado com 3 coisas: (1) na prática não se deve sobrescrever **todos** os calendars como no exemplo; (2) testar o código a cada upgrade do PrimeFaces para verificar se não ocorrem mudanças que quebram o código; (3) cuidado ao manipular o objeto `Date` pois ele virá com algum dia "aleatório", então se o *back end* fizer algum tipo de manipulação nessa data pode incorrer em resultados inesperados.