# Exibir somente horas no componente calendar do Primefaces

Tags: java, primefaces

Como apresentar para o usuário a opção para selecionar apenas horas e minutos no componente `<p:calendar>` do ***Primefaces***

Tenho dois campos com horário de início e fim para selecionar, porém mesmo colocando o `pattern="HH:mm"` ao clicar para selecionar o horário, é mostrado ano, mês, Dia, Hora e Minuto. Gostaria de deixar apenas Hora e Minuto visível para o usuário.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- **Panel Grid com os campos**

```html
<p:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="#{horarioFuncionamentoController.selected != null}">
  <p:outputLabel value="Início" for="inicio" />
  <p:calendar id="inicio" 
      pattern="HH:mm" 
      value="#{horarioFuncionamentoBean.selected.inicio}" 
      title="Início" 
      showOn="button" />
  
  <p:outputLabel value="Fim" for="fim" />
  <p:calendar id="fim" 
    pattern="HH:mm" 
    value="#{horarioFuncionamentoBean.selected.fim}" 
    title="Fim" 
    showOn="button" />
</p:panelGrid>
```

Encontrei um [Post de dois anos atrás](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13280/exibir-somente-m%C3%AAs-e-ano-no-calendar-do-primefaces) sobre um assunto similar, mas acredito que atualmente possa existir alguma solução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente colocar timeOnly="true".

```
<p:calendar id="inicio" value="#{horarioFuncionamentoBean.selected.inicio}" pattern="HH:mm" timeOnly="true" />

<p:calendar id="fim" value="#{horarioFuncionamentoBean.selected.fim}" pattern="HH:mm" timeOnly="true" />
```